# Azure redis deployment failure terminal provisioning

Tags: azure, deployment, redis

I am creating this azure redis resource and getting the terminal provision failure error, tried couple of time getting the same

here is the error

```html
here is the RAW error

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
{"code":"ResourceDeploymentFailure","target":"/subscriptions/xxxxx-484f-4daf-a0bd-xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rg-prod/providers/Microsoft.Cache/redisEnterprise/ redis-cache","message":"The resource write operation failed to complete successfully, because it reached terminal provisioning state 'Failed'."}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the error occurs when there is a configuration issues as per MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-troubleshoot-server) troubleshoot. Check below configuration issues may cause the error.

- There was a problem with the Azure infrastructure, like  a server failure or a network outage. Conflicts may arise because the Redis Cache was set up on a subnet of a Resource Manager [virtual network](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/troubleshooting-azure-redis-connectivity-issues/ba-p/1450361) that also has other resources.
- There are issues with the virtual network settings for the cache, such as the client host machine not being on the same virtual network as the Azure Cache for Redis.
- As shown in below image you can check the error in Support + Troubleshooting and still issue exist you can reach out Microsoft support team.
  [image]
  Refer these MS [document1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1005569/cannot-create-redis-cache-%28premium-tier%29-using-vne)  and [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-configure) it may helps.